Two definitions of algebraic closure
We can define algebraic closure of some field $F$ in two ways, both seem logical:
(1) it is the smallest (with respect to inclusion) algebraically closed field that contains $F$.
(2) it is a field that we got from $F$ once we have extended $F$ with all zeros of all polynomials in $F[x]$.
But, these definitions are not equivalent. In fact, it is obvious that field that we got in (1) would contain a field that we would get in (2). For example why they are different, take $\mathbb{Q}$. On (1) we obviously obtain $\mathbb{C}$. I am not exactly sure what we obtain in (2), but it is a proper subset of $\mathbb{C}$: we can not get stuff like $\pi,e$ and so on...
What is then a standard definition of algebraic closure? I know there is a standard result that algebraic closure of every field exists, but according to which definition?

Why would we get $\Bbb C$ in $(1)$? We would get $\overline{\Bbb Q}$, as an  algebraic closure of $\Bbb Q$. May be, this post is helpful, or this one.

The most standard definition is actually none of the two. Usually algebraic closure is defined as an algebraically closed field that is an algebraic extension of $F$. It is true (but not that obvious) that this is equivalent to the two conditions you wrote.

Does this answer your question? Construct algebraic closure of $\mathbb{Q}$

It makes no sense to talk about "smallest with respect to inclusion". Consider $\mathbb{R}$, and look at all overfields of $\mathbb{R}$ within the Hamiltonians. Which is the "smallest" algebraically closed field containing $\mathbb{R}$. Is it $\mathbb{R}[i]$, $\mathbb{R}[j]$, or $\mathbb{R}[k]$? Or $\mathbb{R}[\alpha]$, where $\alpha$ is any of the infinitely many quaternions satisfying $x^2+1=0$?

@ArturoMagidin My guess is that OP probably meant a minimal algebraically closed field with respect to inclusion, i.e one that doesn't contain any other algebraically closed fields that contain $F$. If so, this is equivalent to being an algebraic closure.

The standard definition of "algebraic closure of a field $F$" is:

The field $K$ is said to be an algebraic closure of $F$ if and only if $K$ is an algebraic extension of $F$, and $K$ is algebraically closed.

Where

A field $L$ is algebraically closed if and only if every nonconstant polynomial with coefficients in $L$ has a root in $L$.

Your (1) is not stated in a correct way, as "smallest" is not something you can do in this situation. Instead, you may say "minimal", in the sense that if $F\subseteq L\subsetneq K$, then $L$ is not algebraically closed.
Your claim that using (1) and starting from $\mathbb{Q}$ you would get $\mathbb{C}$ is also incorrect, using either your incorrect phrasing or the correct one, since $\overline{\mathbb{Q}}$, the field of algebraic numbers, is algebraically closed, contains $\mathbb{Q}$, and is properly contained in $\mathbb{C}$.
Theorem. Let $F$ be a field. The following are equivalent:

Every nonconstant polynomial $f(x)\in F[x]$ has a root in $F$.
Every  nonconstant polynomial $g(x)\in F[x]$ splits over $F$.
Every irreducible polynomial in $F[x]$ has degree one.
There is no algebraic extension of $F$ except $F$ itself.
There is a subfield $K$ of $F$ such that $F$ is algebraic over $K$ and every polynomial in $K[x]$ splits in $F[x]$.

Proof. It is straightforward that 4$\implies$3, that 3$\implies$2, and that 2$\implies$1.
That 1$\implies$4 is as follows: let $K$ be an algebraic extension of $F$, and let $a\in K$. Then $a$ is algebraic, so if $f(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $F$, then $f(x)$ is irreducible. By (1), since $f(x)$ has a root $r$, it follows that $x-r\mid f(x)$, hence $f(x)=x-r$. Since $f(a)=0$, then $f(x)=x-a$, hence $a\in F$. Thus, $K\subseteq F$.
4$\implies$5 by taking $K=F$. To see that 5$\implies$4, let $L$ be an algebraic extension of $F$, and let $a\in L$. Since $a$ is algebraic over $F$ and $F$ is algebraic over $K$, then $a$ is algebraic over $K$. Let $f(x)\in K[x]$ be the minimal polynomial of $a$ over $K$. Then $f(x)$ splits in $F[x]$. By unique factorization, since $x-a$ divides $f(x)$ in $L[x]$, $x-a$ must divide of the factors of $f(x)$ in $F[x]$. But all those factors are linear, and since $f(x)$ is monic, we may assume that all the linear factors of $f(x)$ in $F[x]$ are monic. So $x-a$ is one of the factors, hence $a\in F$. Thus, $F=L$, proving 4. $\Box$
Corollary. Let $K$ be an extension of $F$. The following are equivalent:

$K$ is algebraic over $F$ and $K$ is algebraically closed.
$K$ is the splitting field over $F$ of the set of all nonconstant polynomials in $F[x]$.
$K$ is the splitting field over $F$ of the set of all irreducible polynomials in $F[x]$.

Proof. Clearly, 2 and 3 are equivalent. If $K$ is algebraic over $F$ and algebraically closed, then every nonconstant polynomial in $F[x]$ splits in $K$, so if $L$ is the splitting field of the set of all nonconstant polynomials of $F$, then we may take $F\subseteq L\subseteq K$. Then $L$ is algebraically closed by item 5 of theorem, hence $L$ has no proper algebraic extensions. Since $K$ is algebraic over $L$, then $L=K$. This shows that 1 implies 2. Conversely, if $K$ is the splitting field of all nonconstant polynomials in $F[x]$, then $K$ is algebraic over $F$, and $K$ satisfies item 5 of the theorem, hence is algebraically closed. $\Box$

I think in 5$\implies $4 we don’t need to invoke unique factorization property of $L[x]$. We know $f(x)$ spilts in $F[x]$. Let $f(x)=(x-a_1)\cdots (x-a_n)$ where $a_i\in F$. Since $f(a)=(a-a_1)\cdots (a-a_n)=0$, by elementary property of fields $a-a_i=0$. Thus $a=a_i\in F$.

Also in corollary $1\Rightarrow 2$, since $K$ is algebraic over $F$, $K=X$ where $X$ is the set of all roots of all non constant polynomial in $F[x]$. So there is no need to use item $5$ of theorem.
